# Azure Reporting Service - rsAuthenticationExtensionError

Tags: azure, reporting-services

I have an Azure Reporting Services instance I want to connect to via the Report Execution Web Service. I have referenced [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552871.aspx) to connect. However, I am receiving an error...

The URL of the service is:

`i593ehr-i.reporting.windows.net`

I connected to:

`i593ehr-i.reporting.windows.net/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx`

and downloaded the WSDL file. It should be noted that the documentation used `ReportExecution2010.asmx`, but that didn't direct to a WSDL file... I used the command supplied in the file to generate a proxy class. I then used this code to connect:

```
var service = new ReportExecutionService();
service.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("report", "******", "i593ehr-i.reporting.windows.net");
service.LoadReport2(reportPath, null);
string extension;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamIds;
var reportData = service.Render("PDF", null, out extension, out mimeType, out encoding, out warnings, out streamIds);
File.WriteAllBytes(outputFile, reportData);
```

and it's returning the message:

`The Authentication Extension threw an unexpected exception or returned a value that is not valid: identity==null. (rsAuthenticationExtensionError)`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I needed to use the `LogonUser` method instead of NetworkCredentials, which the documentation specified but I must have overlooked... The code should be:

```
service.LogonUser("report", "******", "i593ehr-i.reporting.windows.net");
```